# FAT32 read next cluster of element

Tags: fat32

Good day
 I have some problem to understand with work of FAT32.When I completely filled root cluster. Do not substitute the information goes to another cluster. And I didn`t understand how find the pointer of this cluster.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the root directory which now spans multiple clusters. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/37137705/2516704 for detailed explanation.